# How to get text between two characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

`|text to get| Other text.... migh have "|"'s ...`

How can I get the `text to get` stuff from the string (and remove it)?

It should be just the first match

Comment: Find the position of the first `|`, then find the position of the second `|`, then get the text in between. There's lots of Javascript documentation online telling you about functions to help you do this, and none of it has anything to do with jQuery really. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
var test_str = "|text to get| Other text.... migh have \"|\"'s ...";
var start_pos = test_str.indexOf('|') + 1;
var end_pos = test_str.indexOf('|',start_pos);
var text_to_get = test_str.substring(start_pos,end_pos)
alert(text_to_get);
```

Comment: @Ella: I note that you picked the short answer. This answer shows a good approach, but _don't forget to check for errors_.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need a regular expression for this; firing up the regex engine is completely overkill for such a simple task.

Just use basic string manipulation:

```
function getSubStr(str, delim) {
    var a = str.indexOf(delim);

    if (a == -1)
       return '';

    var b = str.indexOf(delim, a+1);

    if (b == -1)
       return '';

    return str.substr(a+1, b-a-1);
    //                 ^    ^- length = gap between delimiters
    //                 |- start = just after the first delimiter
}

print(getSubStr('|text to get| Other text.... migh have "|"s ...', '|'));

// Output: text to get
```

### [Live demo.](http://www.ideone.com/uvBf9)

Comment: People get too carried away with the **Don't use Regex** slogan. In general, regular string manipulation is better. But if you need 7 lines of code that way, then you're better off using a 1 liner Regex.

Comment: @Joseph: Nonsense. There is a **vast** performance boost from not joining the "omg let's use regexes for everything" crowd. People get too carried away with the "omg seven lines of code" slogan. And notice that my function is deliberately very verbose; the technique itself need only take a single line.

Comment: Whatever your opinion on the subject, the OP will probably learn more from this answer. +1

Answer (score 5):

To get it:

```
"|text to get| Other text.... migh have \"|\"'s ...".match(/\|(.*?)\|/)
```

To remove it:

```
"|text to get| Other text.... migh have \"|\"'s ...".replace(/\|(.*?)\|/, "")
```

I'm not *the* expert on Regex so if someone has improvements, please edit.

Comment: This'll also remove the pipes

Comment: Consider `/\|(.+?)\|/` if you only want matches of at least one character.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = '|text to get| Other text.... migh have "|"\'s ...';
string = string.replace(/^\|[^|]*\|/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get the text you want by using `match`, then run `replace` with it:

```
var text = "|text to get| Other text.... migh have \"|\"'s ...";
text.replace(text.match(/\|([^|]*)\|/)[1], "");
```

Answer (score -3):

you should look up the following functions:

```
split()
substr()
```

Depending on how you want to solve your task either can be used.

Comment: Please provide an example.