# Create a link within Textarea of CSHTML page in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In CSHTML page, I am displaying text using `@Html.TextArea`. Now I need to create one link within that text. Is that possible to create a link within TextArea?

If it is not possible, what kind of control I can use to display text with link? Any suggestion please.

Ex:

```
@Html.TextArea("MsgTxtBox","Messagewithlinkhere",new { readOnly = true, id = "MsgTxtBox" })
```

Comment: It is tedious task to create link within Textarea. Try using some other controls like label.

Comment: What are you trying to do here. You have made the `<textarea>` readonly so you cannot create anything in it. Are you trying to just display text that includes a link? (if so, do not use a `<textarea>` - just use `<div>@Html.Raw("your message with link")</div>`)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke - Thanks for suggestion. If possible can you please give me an example or any link for reference would be helpful.

Comment: There is an example in my previous comment :)

Comment: @Html.Raw("Message with link here") or simply using `<div>` or `<span>` tags with `<a>` for link(s) should work - no need to use `@Html.TextArea`.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke - Like this I need, @Html.Raw("Hi" <a href="@Url.Action("login", "loginController")" id="lnklogin"
            name="lnklogin" value="login" >click</a> "Here")

Comment: Obviously the message should be built in the controller, but copy the following into a view to see how it works `@{ var msg = "Hi <a href=\"/login\">Click</a> Here"; } @Html.Raw(msg);` (and the `name` and `value` attributes in your `<a>` tag are invalid)

Comment: Thank you so much. Using span works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but you would have to use some javascript and provided there is only one link in the text. Add a javascript onclick event function to the textbox:

```
@Html.TextArea("MsgTxtBox","Messagewithlinkhere",new { readOnly = true, id = "MsgTxtBox", onclick="redirectToUrl()" })
```

Now make sure the links in the text are surrounded by a character like [link], so you can separate them from the text. Lets say the value of the text is "**Hello [https://www.google.com] World**"

Now add the following javascript on top: We would take the index of the first **[** character and then the second one **]**, and use a substring method to get the string in between. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365575/how-to-get-text-between-two-characters), then use window.location to redirect to that link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirectToUrl() {
   var text = document.getElementById("MsgTxtBox").value;
   var start = text.indexOf('[') + 1;
   var end = text.indexOf(']', start);
   var link = text.substring(start, end)
   window.location = link;
}
</script>
```