# How to Extract String between two braces - javascript

Tags: javascript, string, extract, between

I have string like this `{employee name}` some text `{employee designation}` some text `{practice}` some text `{from date}` to `{to date}` `{from date}`
I want employee name,employee designation,practice and so how to do this in javascript

Comment: Can you show your effort by putting sample code? Try to parse yourself first, also include [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get text between two characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365575/how-to-get-text-between-two-characters)

Comment: you can use string.match for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `substring` to get the characters in between the braces

something like:

```
var s='{test}';
var res = s.substring(1, s.length-1);
alert(res);//this will alert test
```

Comment: OP is just asking this : How to Extract String between two braces - javascript

Comment: You don't need a regular expression for this; firing up the regex engine is completely overkill for such a simple task