# Search Placeholder Values in 2 strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, object

I've two strings in JavaScript like

```
var description = "&lt;DP_A&gt;.&lt;Del.Dce Lks.{Link}&gt;.&lt;Pl.Rrs Bk 0.310-PT-304_({strm})&gt;"

var Title = "&lt;DP_A&gt;.&lt;Del.Dce Lks.1&gt;.&lt;Pl.Rrs Bk 0.310-PT-304_(1)&gt;"
```

here {Link} and {strm} are placeholders or more likely whatever comes between { } is placeholder

I need to compare both string like description and Title to find placeholder values, Output needs to be like

```
 {"Link" : 1, "strm" : 1 }
```

or array

```
[{Link" : 1, "strm" : 1}]
```

I've tried some RegEx but not working, any help??

```
 if (description.includes("{")) {
                        var found = [],          // an array to collect the strings that are found
                         rxp = /{([^}]+)}/g,
                         curMatch;
                        while (curMatch = rxp.exec(description)) {
                            found.push(curMatch[1]);
                        }

                       }
```

I'm able to get array of Placeholders but not able to find values into title string.

Comment: Show us what you tried so far, even if that's not working.

Comment: Are they the same string every time.

Comment: `{"Link" : 1, "strm" : 2 }` why is "strm" 2? It appears only once. What do you mean by _I need to compare both string like description and Title to find placeholder values_? do you need to find the index of each?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365575/how-to-get-text-between-two-characters

Comment: @briosheje - `strm` should be equal to `1` for me, but not because of its number of occurences, rather because in `Title`, it is written `1` where `{strm}` is placed in `description`.

Comment: @KévinBibollet Oh. nice guess. That is terribly explained, though. That's way harder than expected, then.

Comment: @briosheje strm or link is basically placeholders which can be anything. anything comes between pair of { } is placeholder and can appear anytime in full description

Comment: @Kévin Bibollet  I've tried using edited section

Comment: @user7417866 It's still unclear why "strm" is 2. The correct output, to me, should be instead `{"Link" : "1", "strm" : "1" }`, am I right?

Comment: @briosheje yes thanks for pointing out.. will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get all parts and then splice the values out of the title string.

```
"&lt;DP_A&gt;.&lt;Del.Dce Lks.{Link}&gt;.&lt;Pl.Rrs Bk 0.310-PT-304_({strm})&gt;",
"&lt;DP_A&gt;.&lt;Del.Dce Lks. 1    &gt;.&lt;Pl.Rrs Bk 0.310-PT-304_( 1    )&gt;";
```

```js
function getParts(pattern, values) {
    var result = {}, value, p1, p2 = 0;
    (pattern.match(/[^{}]+/g) || []).forEach((s, i, a) => {
        if (i % 2) return Object.assign(result, { [s]: value });
        p1 = values.indexOf(s, p2),
        p2 = values.indexOf(a[i + 2], p1);
        value = values.slice(p1 + s.length, p2 === -1 ? undefined : p2);
    });
    return result;
}

var description = "&lt;DP_A&gt;.&lt;Del.Dce Lks.{Link}&gt;.&lt;Pl.Rrs Bk 0.310-PT-304_({strm})&gt;{last}",
    title = "&lt;DP_A&gt;.&lt;Del.Dce Lks.abcdef&gt;.&lt;Pl.Rrs Bk 0.310-PT-304_(ghijklöööö)&gt;fubar";
    
console.log(getParts(description, title));
```

With a `for` statement and reusing known positions.

```js
function getParts(pattern, values) {
    var parts = pattern.match(/[^{}]+/g),
        result = {}, p1, p2, i;
    if (!parts || parts.length < 2) return {};
    p1 = values.indexOf(parts[0]);
    for (i = 1; i < parts.length; i += 2) {
        p2 = values.indexOf(parts[i + 1], p1);
        Object.assign(result, { [parts[i]]: values.slice(p1 + parts[i - 1].length, p2 === -1 ? undefined : p2) });
        p1 = p2;
    }
    return result;
}

var description = "&lt;DP_A&gt;.&lt;Del.Dce Lks.{Link}&gt;.&lt;Pl.Rrs Bk 0.310-PT-304_({strm})&gt;{last}",
    title = "&lt;DP_A&gt;.&lt;Del.Dce Lks.abcdef&gt;.&lt;Pl.Rrs Bk 0.310-PT-304_(ghijklöööö)&gt;fubar";
    
console.log(getParts(description, title));
```

Comment: `( 1    )` <-- are you assuming those have the same length as `({strm})`?..

Comment: which length do you mean?

Comment: You are matching `({strm})&gt;"` on `( 1    )&gt;";` but the OP string rather ends with `(1)&gt;"`. Not sure whether it's intended.

Comment: @NinaScholz didn't see that your example is actually more complex, sorry :P

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace`:

```js
var description = "&lt;DP_A&gt;.&lt;Del.Dce Lks.{Link}&gt;.&lt;Pl.Rrs Bk 0.310-PT-304_({strm})&gt;"
const obj = { 
  Link: 1,
  strm: 2
};
const res = description.replace(/{(.*?)}/g, m => obj[m.slice(1, -1)]);

document.write(res);
```

Comment: I think he is trying to match the placeholders **inside** the Title string, as mentioned in the comments by Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is far more complex than I actually expected.

I'm not actually that good at this kind of operations, but here is a "working" solution: you may want to rewrite it a bit, but still, the concept is actually fair to me.

The steps followed to achieve the results are:

- Acquire all the indexes of "{". I've used a function generator below, but you may use whathever other criteria you want. The goal is to acquire the starting bracket of each match.
- loop each matched bracket, look for the closing bracket and acquire the character just after it in the description string.
- perform the value match upon the Title string.
- Continue by applying currently matched values to update the offsets.
- Map the result to collect the desired output: I've intentionally returned an array of items because a placeholder may exist twice.

Some side notes:

- The below script, as mentioned above, won't take care of limit cases like "{hello{world}".
- The below script can be improved by matching both the previous character and the next character.
- The below script might fail in some situations, it just happens to work in this case, but I didn't test it with limit cases.

```js
var description = "&lt;DP_A&gt;.&lt;Del.Dce Lks.{Link}&gt;.&lt;Pl.Rrs Bk 0.310-PT-304_({strm})&gt;";
var Title = "&lt;DP_A&gt;.&lt;Del.Dce Lks.1&gt;.&lt;Pl.Rrs Bk 0.310-PT-304_(1)&gt;";

// Acquire all the indexes of every "{".
// BEWARE: This will actually fail if the description is "&LT{LLT{hello}", but you may change this.
const descriptionLookupIndexes = [].concat(...(function*(){
  for (var i = 0; i < description.length; i++) {
     if (description[i] === "{") yield [i];
  }
})());

let matches = [];
descriptionLookupIndexes.forEach((i, index) => {
  // acquire the description by replacing the currently known values.
  let _replacedDescription = description;
  let _replacedDescriptionIndex = i - matches.reduce((a,b) => a + b.amount, 0);
  // This foreach will replace the placeholders already found with their respective values.
  matches.forEach(k => {
    let splitted = _replacedDescription.split('');
    splitted.splice(k.from, k.amount, [k.value.split('')]);
    _replacedDescription = splitted.join('');
  });
  // Acquire the relevant portion of the string.
  const needle = _replacedDescription.substring(_replacedDescriptionIndex, _replacedDescription.length);
  // Look for the next character after the first } occurrence in the current substring.
  const nextChar = needle[needle.indexOf("}") + 1];
  // Acquire the relevant substring for the title.
  const titleNeedle = Title.substring(_replacedDescriptionIndex, Title.length);
  matches.push({
    from: _replacedDescriptionIndex,
    amount: needle.match(/[^{\}]+(?=})/g)[0].length + 1,
    needle: needle.match(/[^{\}]+(?=})/g)[0],
    value: titleNeedle.substring(0, titleNeedle.indexOf(nextChar))
  });
});

// Matches is now the array with all the occurrences, let's just map it to acquire a new array of objects with the desired format.
// BEWARE: If multiple keys exists, they will be mapped to an array.

const res = matches.reduce((acc, next) => {
  acc[next.needle] = acc[next.needle] || [];
  acc[next.needle].push({
    [next.needle]: next.value
  });
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```